# possible causes of infinite wait in pthread_cond_wait

Tags: c, multithreading, synchronization, pthreads

I am currently trying to analyse a issue in third party source code where a thread (code snippet corresponding to `THREAD-T1`) is in infinite wait state. The suspicion is that the thread is stuck in `pthread_cond_wait`. The following are the details of the same.

**Code description**

- T1 does an asynchronous call to an API exposed by T2.
- Hence T1 moves to a blocking wait on a conditional variable (say `cond_t`).
- The conditional variable `cond_t` is signalled in the callback event generated by T2.
- The above cycle is repeated `n` times until the API returns success.

To consolidate, the above is a series of steps which makes the asynchronous call similar to a synchronous one by the use of condition variables.

**Sample code**

```
   #define MAX_RETRY (3)
   bool            g_b_ret_val;       
   pthread_mutex_t g_cond_mutex;
   pthread_mutex_t g_ret_val_mutex; /* Assume iniitailzed in the main thread */
   pthread_cond_t  g_cond_t; /* Assume iniitailzed in the main thread */

   retry_async_call_routine()  /* Thread-T1 */
   {
       while(( false == g_b_ret_val) && (retry < MAX_RETRY))
       {
           (void)invoke_async_api();
           pthread_mutex_init(&g_cond_mutex, NULL);
           pthread_mutex_lock(&g_cond_mutex);
           pthread_cond_wait(g_cond_t, &g_cond_mutex);
           pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_cond_mutex);
           pthread_mutex_destroy(&g_cond_mutex);
           retry ++ ;
        }
   }

   callback_routine() /* Thread-T2 */
   {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
        g_b_ret_val = true; /* May be false also on failure */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&g_cond_t);
   }
```

**Known issues that I see in the code**

1. Missing retest of condition in a while loop on `pthread_cond_wait`
2. Missing mutex lock while signalling

**Questions**

1. Please point out me on any more loop holes (or) possibility of infinite wait (if any).
2. `g_cond_t` is not reset using `pthread_cond_destroy` between successive waits, what is  the behaviour of the same ? ( Any references regarding this)

Answer (score 2):

This code seems absurd.  You are not supposed to create and destroy a mutex just so you can wait on the condition variable.  A mutex needs to be created before thread-shared data are used, then the mutex must be used to protect the shared data.  In this case, that's `g_ret_val_mutex` which protects `g_b_ret_val`.

The condition variable itself is just used for waiting (with regular or timed wait) and signaling (signal or broadcast).  It generally does not need its own lock, and in fact, having a separate one (as in the above loop) gets in the way of calling `pthread_cond_wait`, which takes only *one* mutex to unlock, not two.  There's no need to destroy and re-create condition variables unless you need new/different attributes.

The key to "not getting stuck"—avoiding infinite wait—is to guarantee that, whenever a thread calls `pthread_cond_wait`, there is definitely some other thread that will, in the future, call `pthread_cond_signal` (or `pthread_cond_broadcast`).  That is, the waiter tests "why to wait" first, *with the "why" part locked*, then waits only if the "why" part says "you should wait".  The wake-up thread may use the *same* lock to determine that a wake-up is necessary, or—if the wake-up thread is "lazy", as in the above example—simply issues a "wake up call" every time.

The minimal change for correctness would thus seem to be to change the loop to read:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
for (retry = 0; retry < MAX_RETRY && !g_b_ret_val; retry++) {
    (void)invoke_async_api();
    pthread_cond_wait(&g_cond_t, &g_ret_val_mutex);
}
success = g_b_ret_val; /* if false, we failed */
/* or: success = retry < MAX_RETRY; -- same result */
pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
```

(Aside: `g_cond_t` is a terrible name for a variable; the `_t` suffix is meant for types.)

---

It's sometimes wise to separate "some thread needs a wake-up" from "final result of that thread is success".  If needed, I'd probably add that using a second boolean.  Let's call it `g_waiting`, which we set `true` when `callback_routine()` is (supposedly) guaranteed to be called and it should do a wake-up event, and `false` when it's not guaranteed to be called or the wakeup is not required.  This kind of coding allows you to switch to `pthread_cond_timedwait`, in case the asynchronous event might never occur for some reason.

Given that `g_ret_val_mutex` protects `g_b_ret_val`, it's appropriate to use that for the "waiting" flag as well—adding another mutex just offers more opportunities for problems, here.  So now we get:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
for (retry = 0; retry < MAX_RETRY && !g_b_ret_val; retry++) {
    (void)invoke_async_api();
    compute_wakeup_time(&abstime);
    g_waiting = true;
    pthread_cond_timedwait(&g_cond_t, &g_ret_val_mutex, &abstime);
    if (g_waiting) {
        /* timeout occurred, we never got our callback */
        /* may want something special for this case */
    } else {
        /* wakeup occurred, result is in g_b_ret_val */
    }
}
success = g_b_ret_val;
/* or: success = retry < MAX_RETRY; */
g_waiting = false;
pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
```

Meanwhile:

```
callback_routine() /* Thread-T2 */
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
    g_b_ret_val = compute_success_or_failure();
    if (g_waiting) {
        g_waiting = false;
        pthread_cond_signal(&g_cond_t);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&g_ret_val_mutex);
}
```

I've moved the `signal` to "inside" the mutex, although it's OK either way, so that I can do it only if `g_waiting` is set, and clear `g_waiting`.  Since we hold the mutex, it's OK to clear `g_waiting` either before or after calling `pthread_cond_signal` (as long as no other code will interrupt the sequence).

Note: if we do start using `timedwait`, we need to find out whether it is OK to call `invoke_async_api` when another earlier `invoke` was used but no result was returned before the timeout.